# Why not validate a Camel Uri using java.net.URI

Tags: java, apache-camel

I had a colleague ask me, why I don't create the uris for a camel component (consumer/producer) using javas URI class:

```java
from(java.net.URI.create(someUriString).toString())
```

The reason this might make sense is, that there is automatic validation for the given uri, before it is interpreted by camel (when the uri is in part loaded from a configuration file, some validation could be useful).

The thing is, that I have never seen anybody create a camel uri like this, everybody just uses plain Strings.
Is there a reason, why we never use java.net.URI to validate a uri for camel, or is there even a drawback in doing it?

Comment: Most probably because camel itself will validate the validity of the URL, since it needs to extract information out of it.

Comment: Because it's not always a URI. For instance look at https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/http4-component.html